# Restoring OTP bit after using MSD boot feature

Tags: pi-3, usb, boot, sd-card, config.txt

I have read on the official Raspberry Pi website that it is possible, by adding a line, `program_usb_boot_mode=1`, to the `/boot/config.txt` file, to flash a Pi3 with the instruction to boot from USB instead of SD Card and - after it's done - a change to the One Time Programmable bit would cause the Pi not to require an SD Card at all anymore, being it able to boot directly off of a USB drive.

I'm interested in doing this though I wonder: since everyone on the Internet (Foundation included) says it's a permanent change that cannot be undone, if I may ever wish to revert this change on my Pi so I can boot from SD, would I be able to do it or would I have to purchase a new Raspberry Pi? And if it is possible what would I have to do? Would booting from a Mass Storage Device containing a config file with the same line except zero value suffice?

Comment: If the Foundation says this is a permanent change why do you doubt it?

Comment: @SteveRobillard because it said that "all **changes** are permanent", which could mean that there is no "restore-all" panic button but it might be possible to overwrite them applying other "permanent" changes on top of those.

Comment: That would kind of redefine the word permanent now wouldn't it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand this is an old question, but happens that I knew how this is working trying to fix a similar problem (more on this later on).

Yes you can boot again from the sdcard, even with the (permanent) OTP bit set, simply because that bit says to the Pi to look further for the bootcode, after checking onto the sdcard, scanning also USB devices etc.

So, you have to **move** the boot files from the vfat *boot* partition on your USB drive towards the sdcard.

In your `cmdline.txt` now you can even set the root to be something as `root=PARTUUID=01eg1a28-02` and enjoy leaving another USB drive inserted during boot (this is what I was trying to fix: if the boot is done completely from the USB drive, in `cmdline.txt` must be set `root=/dev/sda2`; don't ask me why).

More on the "bootflow" here:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md

Comment: In other words, if you don't have a bootable USB drive inserted, and you specify the correct boot media in the config file on the SD Card, you can still boot from the SD Card even with the OTPB flashed?

Comment: Yes, and since the sdcard is scanned first (searching for the bootcode) you can even leave the USB drive inserted.

Comment: Thanks. So basically setting the OTP is an addition, not a replacement. This answers my question

Comment: Yes. Did you try yourself? Is it working?